# Lower system call perfermance on aarch64 vs. x86-64

Tags: kernel, arm, system-calls, perf

Does anyone know why system calls take longer to execute on 64-bit ARM (aarch64) compared to 64-bit Intel CPUs (x86-64)? Please see below my benchmarking setup.

- 64-bit ARM CPU: Ampere Altra Q80-30, 80 cores, 3 GHz
- 64-bit Intel CPU: Intel Xeon Gold 5317 CPU, 12 cores (24 threads), frequency set to maximum 3 GHz

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Linux Kernel: 5.13.0-41-generic (on both ARM and Xeon)

Benchmark: UnixBench syscall (https://github.com/kdlucas/byte-unixbench) (https://github.com/kdlucas/byte-unixbench/blob/master/UnixBench/src/syscall.c)

Command to run: ./syscall 10 (for mixed sys calls) or ./syscall 10 close (only with close())

I profiled the execution with perf and got the following results (for ./syscall 10 close):

```
                       Altra             Xeon
Duration [s]                  10              10
Throughput [lps]      23,194,919      47,938,768
Cycles            30,000,710,570  29,968,373,641
Instructions      37,767,647,457  40,044,878,500
IPC                         1.26            1.34
Calls                231,949,190     479,387,680
Instructions per call     162.83           83.53
```

So at the same frequency (3 GHz), Xeon executes double the number of system calls compared to Altra. Altra needs 2X the number of instructions per call (163 vs. 84). Is there any architectural (aarch64 vs. x86-64) reason for this?

Comment: Very interesting. The very first obvious thing I would think of in terms of arch differences inducing major performance impact is Intel ©®™ *hyperthreading* however, it is not yet obvious to me how this would be related to that specific test you carried. I'll need to have a look to the Byte's code I do not know.